# ImageView over ImageView in Android

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I have to do ImageView over ImageView, and they have the same dimensions and have to be one over the other at the exact same place and at times I have to do this for like 3 ImageViews to  be on top of each other. Anyone has any idea how this should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this will place the 3 image on top of each other.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="<some_size>dp"
            android:layout_height="<some_size>dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/<name_of_asset>" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="<some_size>dp"
            android:layout_height="<some_size>dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/<name_of_asset>" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="<some_size>dp"
            android:layout_height="<some_size>dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/<name_of_asset>" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Which will be over the other? I mean the second will cover the first and the third will be over both of them?

Comment: In Android, the 1st item defined in a layout will always be below the next one.

Answer (score 1):

Using `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` you can do it for n number of `ImageViews`. Just declare it one below another and they will cover each other. First declared would be behind the second declared and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Just tweak it to suit your needs.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]